# Definition of $L^p$ norm of a vector-valued function

Tags: real-analysis, definition, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

If $u$ is a vector the definition of the discrete norm will be
$$\|u\|_{l^p}=(\sum |u_i|^p)^{1/p},$$
If $u$ is a function, 
$$\|u\|_{L^p}=\left(\int|u|^p\right)^{1/p}$$
But when $u$ is a vector-valued function, what is the definition of $\|u\|_{L^p}$?

Should we use the definition of norm for each element of $u$ or   should we first use the definition of discrete norm then use continuous norm definition?

Comment: The question, as of now, is unclear to me. The $\ell^p$ norm and $L^p$ norm are norms on different vectors spaces. If you are in $V = \Bbb R^n$, you can equip it with the $\ell^p$ norm. If you are in $V = C^0([a, b])$, the vector spaces of all continuous functions on $[a,b]$, you can equip it with the $L^p$ norm. But it doesn't make sense to say $\|u\|_{L^p}$ if $u$ is a "vector". It needs to be a function. (Vector is the standard terminology for elements of $\Bbb R^n$).

Comment: I have to agree, you're talking about different vector spaces so they have different norms, albeit you get $\ell^p$ norm from $L^p$ by using counting measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that by "$u$ is a vector", you mean "$u$ is a vector-valued function", right?

In this case, indeed the definition would be to use the definition of $l^p$ norm inside the integral term.

Comment: In case anyone is interested why this would be a norm, have a look at [these lecture notes](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~kalenda/data/fa116e-10.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

In physics vector-valued $L^{2}$-functions occur frequently. As an example
let $f$ be a function from $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ into the vector space $V$ with $%
|.|_{V}$ the norm on $V$. Then we denote the $L^{p}$-space as $L^{p}(\mathbb{%
R}^{n},V,d^{n}x)$ or something similar. Now
\begin{equation*}
\parallel f\parallel _{p}^{p}=\int d^{n}x|f(x)|_{V}^{p}
\end{equation*}
In the common case of complex-valued $f$ we thus have $L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n},
\mathbb{C},d^{n}x)$ where $\mathbb{C}$is usually omitted.